# How we can hide the URL in Jquery file using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I call many functions via ajax but call URLs are visible. How we can hide (or encrypt) those URLs in the client machine

Comment: It depends on what you mean by hide? All Ajax calls will be seen within the developer toolbar of any browser, therefore rendering any trickery used to hide them in the source code.

My question would be, why do you want to hide them? If you are doing so to prevent others calling them externally, change your webserver configuration such that only localhost or IP specific hosts can access the URL's.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide the JS pages. They are in readable form. Some webapps suggest `debug = false` in compilation tag in web.config which can stop user to open files from chrome but user can visit the scripts folder to see the file. 
The only way to hide it from the browser is to keep it entirely within the server.